# Best way to manage background images with responsive design?

Tags: html, css, image

On a website where a non-tileable background image is used, what is the best way to make this look good across all devices/all zooms?

The CSS is

background: #aaa url(//url);

So a background colour is used where the image ends.

My initial thoughts are to give the background image a size of 100%, so regardless of the zoom or the viewport size, the background image will never be lose quality.

Is this a good way to do it or is there another, better way to manage background images in responsive design?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend this

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Source: [CSS-Tricks: Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: By the way dwreck08, on larger screens obviously the background image will lose quality, what are your recommendations? A large image resolution? What kind of size would be best? Any ideas?